# ASP.NET: First Chance to add something to HttpContext

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-mvc-5, httpcontext

We are using the [HttpContext.Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.110).aspx) to save our own SecurityContext.

```
public static ISecurityContext Current {          
     get {
        if (!(HttpContext.Current.Items["SecurityContext"] is ISecurityContext)) {
            HttpContext.Current.Items["SecurityContext"] = new SecurityContext(...);
        }
        return HttpContext.Current.Items["SecurityContext"] as ISecurityContext;

     }
}
```

Now the problem is, where to create the SecurityContext and add it to the HttpContext. When looking at the [MVC-Lifecycle](http://www-asp.azureedge.net/v-2016-08-02-001/media/4773381/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application.pdf) I guess that an `IAuthenticationFilter` is the first chance to do that. Would this be a good idea or is there an even better "place" to add the SecurityContext to the HttpContext?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want some sort of [Service Locator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). An [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) might be a good option for you used with a [Dependency Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) style of building the controllers. In this way you don't have to bother when `HttpContext` is ready to use.

To answer your question.
In `global.asax` use the `Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute` method to instantiate and store the service implementation.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var context = (sender as HttpApplication).Context;
            context.Items.Add("IService", new Service());
        }
```

Because this method is executed even before any controller is created, then implementation it will be then available. You can create a service locator class which retrieves the instance.

```
 public class ServiceLocator
    {
        public static IService Current
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Items["IService"] as IService;
            }
        }
    }
```

And use this class in a controller.

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = ServiceLocator.Current.Now.ToString();
            return View();
        }
    .........
```

Comment: What are the cons for using an IAuthenticationFilter to create and set the SecurityContext?

Comment: If you don't intend to use the SecurityContext object before the IAuthenticationFilter is used, then there are no cons.

Comment: Just it seems odd to use an authentication filter in this scenario.

Comment: Do you see any scenarios, where to use the SecurityContext before authentication? And yes, it seems little odd, but we prefere not using the "magic-methods" in global.asax.

Comment: Yes, use DI and let the framework to inject the dependency in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a longer term storage, such as session state rather than `HttpContext.Current.Items`, only because using the latter is a shorter scope (per HTTP request) meaning you have to set the `SecurityContext` each request. (Unless that is a requirement of course.)

Using session state means you can create the context once and store that in session state for future use (until the session expires).

**Storing**

`Session["SecurityContext"] = new SecurityContext();`

**Reading**

```
var context = Session["SecurityContext"] as SecurityContext;

if (context != null) {
//.......
}
```

Comment: Session does not seem to be a good solution, because where a using NHibernate with Session per request. When using the SecurityContext with a domainobject (e.g. the current user), than nhibernate would throw an exception.